# std.json - Any way to check if a JSONValue has a particular field

Tags: json, d, phobos

Suppose I have an unknown bit of JSON, and I want to check if it has a form similar to this:

```
{
    "foo": stuff
    "bar": stuff
}
```

where `stuff` is anything - integer, object, whatever. If I do something like this:

```
auto json = parseJSON("{}");
auto foo = json["foo"];
```

I will get a segfault. Is there any way to gracefully handle this (return null, throw exception, *anything* other than a segfault)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the D `in` operator, like with a D associative array:

```
auto foo = "foo" in json ? json["foo"].str : null;
```

If you're using DMD 2.065 or older, you need to use `json.object` for the `in` operator:

```
auto foo = "foo" in json.object ? json["foo"].str : null;
```

Comment: My compiler doesn't like that very much - that line yields the error ``rvalue of in expression must be an associative array, not JSONValue``.

Comment: Try `"foo" in json.object`, then.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Could you edit your answer so that other people don't make my mistake, please?

Comment: Done. `json.object` is only needed for DMD 2.065 or older.